# On MacOS, create a desktop shortcut and prevent it from being deleted

Tags: macos, shortcuts, symbolic-link

How can I create a desktop shortcut to a network share, and prevent it from being deleted (perhaps by a non-root user?)

Comment: Is the question about creating a shortcut (drag&drop) or about protecting it from being deleted (chmod 755 chown root)?

Comment: The question misses the entire point of having individual accounts... if you make a shortcut on your desktop then it won't even appear on anyone else's, so assuming no malicious intent from another admin, no-one else would ever even see it. If you have more than one user to one account, then you get what you pay for :/

Comment: @Tetsujin I can imagine a situation where you have someone who is not very adept with computers and you just want to make sure they don't muck things up, intentionally or otherwise. One less trip to tech support. I suppose you could `crontab` the creation of the shortcut, but then you might have to ask, "have you turned it off and on?"

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to do this; either by locking the alias file, or with an access control list:

- Option 1, locking the file (note: only the owner is allowed to unlock):

  ```
  # Create alias however you want to, then...
  sudo chown root /Users/ensnare/Desktop/AliasFile
  sudo chflags uchg /Users/ensnare/Desktop/AliasFile
  ```
- Option 2, access control list:

  ```
  # Create alias however you want to, then...
  sudo chown root /Users/ensnare/Desktop/AliasFile
  sudo chmod 644 /Users/ensnare/Desktop/AliasFile
  sudo chmod +a "group:everyone deny delete" /Users/ensnare/Desktop/AliasFile
  ```

Note that @lungj's statement that deletion is controlled by the parent directory's permissions os *mostly* true, but both of these options override that and prevent moving, renaming, or deleting the file.

Comment: Much better answer than mine!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is an acceptable answer for your situation (and not sure if macOS has a special mechanism to accomplish what you want), but the permissions to delete a file actually come from the directory itself. So if you want to prevent a file from being deleted, you need to remove write access to the directory for the user(s) in question. This means that you can make the entire `~/Desktop` directory read-only and let users create files in a subdirectory on the desktop or you can create a directory that is read-only on the desktop and put your shortcut there, hoping no one will delete it.

```
# Shortcuts directly on desktop. Now, users have to delete the Desktop directory to remove the shortcuts.
mkdir ~/Desktop/read-write # Create directory where users can add/remove data.
### Add your links to the Desktop.
sudo chown root ~/Desktop # Don't own everything inside, just the directory itself.
chmod -r ~/Desktop # Prevent users from adding/removing files on the desktop.

# Shortcuts in a directory on the desktop. Users have to delete this directory to remove your shortcuts, but can add/remove stuff on the desktop freely.
mkdir ~/Desktop/link_directory # Create directory for your links.
### Add your links to the directory.
sudo chown root ~/Desktop/link_directory
chmod -r ~/Desktop/link_directory # Prevent users from adding/removing files in the link directory.
```

You'll probably also want to take away write permissions for the links to prevent malicious actions from users. The first approach is probably a little bit safer, when combined with making the root home directory read-only, too, since normal users can't replace the links on the desktop.

Comment: a) don't ever use root on Mac [it's disabled by default & really should never be needed if you are on the sudoers list] b) anything you can do another admin account can undo. If no malicious intent, there is no visible issue on separate accounts, as each has its own ~/Desktop

Comment: I'm thinking this is a public workstation-stye setup where a user might stay logged in and someone comes in afterwards. Also, I'm not really sure what you mean by "don't ever use root on Mac". That seems like a very strong generalization. Every time you `sudo`, you're "using root". And I need to use root a lot. I'm also assuming OP meant "non-root user" as an account not added as an administrator (and thus not in the shudders file).

Comment: DYAC: that should read "sudoers file", not "shudders file".